# Extracting name of stored procedures from a file, if a particular table is used in it using regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a SQL file in which more than one stored procedures are there. I have been given a table name and need to find out in which stored procedure is that table used. It would be nice if answer is given in C#.

Eg. Given two procedures an table name "ucg2.userCompanyId" , we need to tell that which procedure use it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[ActiveUsersAM_prc]    
--ActiveUsers_getdata_prc    
    @Usercompanyid varchar(max)    
AS     
Begin    


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ActiveUserCompany') IS NOT NULL  
DROP TABLE #ActiveUserCompany  

CREATE TABLE #ActiveUserCompany  
(userCompanyId INT)  

INSERT INTO #ActiveUserCompany  
SELECT val FROM dbautil.dbo.Split_fn(@userCompanyID,',')  


CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_usercompanyId ON #ActiveUserCompany(userCompanyId)  

SELECT * FROM dbo.ActiveUsersAMCache_tbl (nolock)
WHERE userCompanyId IN (SELECT userCompanyId FROM #ActiveUserCompany (nolock))

END
```

and

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[ActiveUsersRelatedCompanies_prc]  
    @Usercompanyid INT
AS     
Begin  

select * 
FROM dbo.ActiveUsersRelatedCompanies_tbl (NOLOCK)
WHERE userCompanyId in (
        select  ucg2.userCompanyId
        from    userCompanyGrouping_tbl u
                inner join userCompanyGrouping_tbl ucg2
                    on isNull(u.subParentCompanyId,u.parentCompanyId) = 
                        (case when u.subParentCompanyId is not null then ucg2.subParentCompanyId 
                            else ucg2.parentCompanyId end)
        where   u.userCompanyId = @userCompanyID
)       
order by userCompanyName, userGroup, fullName
END
```

Comment: What do you have available to do this? Only a simple regex search like in Notepad++ etc.? Or something more sophisticated like PowerShell?

Comment: @marsze 
I have to find it through the regex library of C#. No sohisticated tools like powergrep, astrogrep, etc. are are used. I jsut want the small algo for doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some simplifications in here, but it should provide a good start.

```
// Read content
string content = File.ReadAllText(filename);
// Separate procedures from each other
// (you might have to use "ToUpper()" before)
string[] procs = content.Split(new string[] { "CREATE PROCEDURE" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
// Check if one of them contains the table name
string table = "ucg2.userCompanyId";
foreach (string proc in procs)
{
    // If it does, print the first line (which holds the name of the stored procedure
    // (Using regex here might be necessary, depending on the source)
    if (proc.Contains(table))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(proc.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]);
    }
}
```